# Fixing /bin/executable on OS X

Tags: rpath, zipalign

I believe that "brew update" has destroyed my /bin/zipalign - since after that it does not run anymore.  The box is at a remote location (10 hours time zone difference, in a server box so I cannot get physical access to push cmd+r).  I can sudo but that does not fix the issue.

How do I solve this?

```
$ /bin/zipalign
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/../lib in /bin/zipalign being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/lib in /bin/zipalign being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.dylib
  Referenced from: /bin/zipalign
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

$ /Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign
Zip alignment utility
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
...
* So that works; I would like to have the that in /bin/zipalign; I though creating a symlink.

$ sudo rm -rf /bin/zipalign
rm: /bin/zipalign: Operation not permitted

$ otool -L /bin/zipalign
/bin/zipalign:
    @rpath/libc++.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

$ sudo install_name_tool -change @rpath/libc++.dylib /share/android/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/libc++.dylib /bin/zipalign
error: 
install_name_tool: can't open input file: /bin/zipalign for writing (Operation not permitted)

$ sudo csrutil disable
csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.
```

This is a Jenkins slave, access: ssh only, can sudo, cannot touch the real keyboard, how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the xcode tools installed? Looks like your system can't find the C++ library. `xcode-select --install`

Comment: What does `otool -l /bin/zipalign` show? (Add it to your question)

Comment: Homebrew will never write to `/bin`. Also, `/bin/zipalign` doesn't exist on my Mac, which suggests that you put it there yourself at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned to be the solution: Copy a file into /usr/bin and make sure it has precedence over /bin and then the botched application will not run.